# Got a warning to replace window.web3 by window.ethereum

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js

I am completely new to web3 . I have been trying to build basic project of blockchain  .Where I have a app.js file . I was supposed to see "app loading " or a account address at the console . I am assuming I have to change window.web3 to window.ethereum  .How to fix this

I have got a waring saying

> inpage.js:1 You are accessing the MetaMask window.web3.currentProvider shim. This property is deprecated; use window.ethereum instead. For details, see:

Here is my code below:

```
App = {
  loading: false,
  contracts: {},

  load: async () => {
    await App.loadWeb3()
    await App.loadAccount()
    await App.loadContract()
    await App.render()
  },

  // https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8
  loadWeb3: async () => {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
    } else {
      window.alert("Please connect to Metamask.")
    }
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum)
      try {
        // Request account access if needed
        await ethereum.enable()
        // Acccounts now exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */})
      } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
      }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
      window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
      // Acccounts always exposed
      web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */})
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
      console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    }
  },

  loadAccount: async () => {
    // Set the current blockchain account
    App.account = web3.eth.accounts[0]
    console.log(App.account)
  }  
}

$(() => {
  $(window).load(() => {
    App.load()
  })
})
```

here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Dapp University | Todo List</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
      main {
        margin-top: 60px;
      }

      #content {
        display: none;
      }

      form {
        width: 350px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      ul {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }

      #completedTaskList .content {
        color: grey;
        text-decoration: line-through;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
      <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/free-download" target="_blank">Dapp University | Todo List</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
        <li class="nav-item text-nowrap d-none d-sm-none d-sm-block">
          <small><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span id="account"></span></a></small>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <main role="main" class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div id="loader" class="text-center">
            <p class="text-center">Loading...</p>
          </div>
          <div id="content">
            <!-- <form onSubmit="App.createTask(); return false;">
              <input id="newTask" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add task..." required>
              <input type="submit" hidden="">
            </form> -->
            <ul id="taskList" class="list-unstyled">
              <div class="taskTemplate" class="checkbox" style="display: none">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                  <span class="content">Task content goes here...</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </ul>
            <ul id="completedTaskList" class="list-unstyled">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/truffle-contract/dist/truffle-contract.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not your personal code writing service.  You have the answer *with examples* to your problem in the documentation you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all instances of `window.web3.currentProvider` with `window.ethereum`, as the error message says.

Or, in your case, remove these lines:

```
-    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
-      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
-      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
-    } else {
-      window.alert("Please connect to Metamask.")
-    }
```